# I'm getting checksum failed error on BouncyCastle FIPS Distribution

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I'm try to use BouncyCastle Provider FIPS distro on Android. When i implemented like this(gradle);

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bc-fips
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:1.0.2.3'
```

I'm getting this checksum error;

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: expected [735510be1bb5157434c14d1e1ca9844b6971634fc03481d93eec75ff27b27034] got [5437fdce4c8eb4f5929e33cec3ebb59ce78f809343d7523121d534dbfd714752]
```

and after i try to add like that but i'm getting same error like this too.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['bc-fips-1.0.2.3.jar.jar'])
```

What should i do? Do I have to re-sign the package?

Comment: Hi, do you get any solution about this issue ? I have similar error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not reach the result either. Implementing BouncyCastle on Android is a very complicated issue. They officially support Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, and Oreo versions in the "org.stripycastle" package. Although it is not certain, I think they provide access to current Android versions through the early access program. They are explained in the frequently asked questions section in the link below.
[link](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html) _italic_